# Are questions asking for further use-cases for feature X on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation, list-questions

Sometimes when learning about a coding feature and starting to use it, I feel like there are more use-cases than what I am using it for.

So I'm tempted to ask a question like :"I'm using feature X to do Y, what are other use-cases for this feature" , but I'm pretty sure that that kind of a question is considered too broad or off topic because there could be any number of answers to that question.

Is this correct?

If so, is there a SE site where this kind of question is welcome?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/list-questions/info

Comment: Not an SE site, but I came across this site which may be of some use to you http://www.slant.co/, it seems to specialize in list based questions.

Comment: I find that if the feature is easily identifiable with a function, method, class or whatever of a specific language... then a good search and research is the best way to see what others use it for. And you'd probably hit SO for the other, less known, use cases ;) If you don't, then it may very well be appropriate to post a good specific question and answer for posterity.

Answer (score 20):

I would vote to close a question like that as too broad.

I do not know of any other SE site for a question like that.

Comment: Same applies, in spades, to questions which ask for *any* use cases: 'what is the point of feature X?'

Comment: @EJP - so you're saying this question is off topic?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used

Comment: @AdamRackis As the first comment to that question says, yes.

Comment: It always males me sad seeing meta arguments that, if followed, would cause excellent information on Stack Overflow to not exist.

Comment: @AdamRackis You say "information", I say "opinion, conjecture, arguments".

Comment: @MrLister - if those highly rated answers are opinions and conjecture, then you have a myopic definition of those words.

Answer (score 12):

I say it depends. That kind of question can be very broad or quite specific. Suppose you see the question:

> I'm learning the Blub language, and I discovered feature X. It seems to me, though, that feature X is pretty much identical to feature Y, with the exception that it is inferior with respect to consideration Z. So why would you ever want to use feature X? In what kinds of scenarios could it ever make sense?

To me this sounds like a very good question, focused on coding techniques and/or algorithms. It may, in fact, have a very specific answer. "Yes, in most situations you want Feature Y. But you would use Feature X in any situation where precisely this, that, and the other hold true. Here is why."

The main difference between this example and your example is that you already have come up with some use-case for the feature. But that doesn't *necessarily* mean your question is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

The key here is to avoid asking for a list. If you're willing to put in some extra effort, you could write code that uses feature X to solve a specific, well-defined, simple problem, and then post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where [specific best practices are on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you're in the early stages of learning a language and can't see why having a specific feature is justified, I would postpone asking a new question until you are able to follow the advice I mentioned above. The full utility of the feature may be an advanced topic that's best left until later, and asking a new question with only rudimentary knowledge may only lead you down a path you would've followed anyway.